# C++: Weird shared library error - eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, cuda

I'm trying to compile some code. Here is the error I'm getting:

`error while loading shared libraries: libcudart.so.4: cannot open shared object file`

Now I've included `/usr/local/cuda/include` and linked to `/usr/local/cuda/lib` and passed the -lcudart flag on the compile prompt.

Yet I still get this run-time error!

I've just started using Eclipse, and this is *really* annoying.

Any insight greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This usually happens with old code when they change the folder structure. Locate where the file is expected in the old code, then make a sym link to where it actually is.

Also try launching eclipse as root. Or running:

```
ldconfig /usr/local/cuda/lib
```

Answer (score 3):

By default the runtime linker won't see stuff in /usr/local/cuda/lib. You need to explicitly tell it to look there. There are several methods:

1. Set up the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to contain `/usr/local/cuda/lib`.
2. Run `ldconfig /usr/local/cuda/lib` as root.
3. Add `-rpath=/usr/local/cuda/lib` to your linker arguments (`-Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/cuda/lib` if linking with `g++`).

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same error. I am using eclipse Juno with Cuda under Ubuntu 10.04. The problem was that while I wad already configured the linker path to point to `/usr/local/cuda/lib64` (in `~/.bashrc` etc), eclipse still couldn't find it. I could run the compiled (via eclipse) project from terminal, but it couldn't link in eclipse's terminal after trying to `Run`.

My solution was to add the variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with value `/usr/local/cuda/lib64` in `File->Properties->Run/Debug Settings->Edit (Selected project)->Environment Tab`

I don't know if there's a more permanent solution but it worked for me.
I should also mention that I had already added accordingly some extra variables in the Building Environment (`C/C++ Build->Environment` in the properties window) because I couldn't build the project for the same reason.

The only weird thing is that at first it could run without problem and then when I reopened eclipse, this error appeared without me changing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Does the file exist, with the expected name in the right directory? Does the symlink (I assume you have one pointing to the versioned .so) point to the right, and a valid, shared object? Do you have read permissions for that file?

Now, you say this is a runtime error while trying to compile the code. Do you mean you can compile, then when you run the error occurs, or the error happens when you try to run the compiler (a linker error)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Yes, the file exists (it's a symbolic link). I'm pretty sure it's the right directory (/usr/local/cuda/lib) as I can see the link inside it. I have read permission on the file. Yes, it's a linker error...